# How to write the basic test message on PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I am a quite newbee for phpunit, so it might be stupid though ....
I google around but not found.

This is my code and I have multiple API and URL to test.

```
namespace Acme\TopBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();


        echo ("first test");
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/api/getplaceinfo');
        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());

        echo ("second test");
        echo('test :' + '/api/getmetainfo/kibichuo');
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/api/getcat');
        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());

        echo ("third test");
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/admin/dashboard');    
        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("My Server")')->count() > 0);


    }
}
```

then I test like this (I am using symfony2 framework)

```
whitebear$ phpunit -c app/
PHPUnit 4.8.35 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.0

Time: 3.69 seconds, Memory: 109.25MB

OK (1 test, 7 assertions)
```

There is no message I expected by echo("first test").

So, even error happens, I can't tell which url shows the error.

My basic idea is wrong??

Comment: very strange, in your test class are 3 assert (instead of the 7 dumped as message), try launching with debug info  `phpunit -c --debug app/` and see what happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write one test for each test and in `assertTrue` you can put a message there.

Example:

```
     public function testThirdTest() { 
      $client = static::createClient();      
      $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/admin/dashboard');    
      $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("My Server")')->count() > 0, 'third test goes wrong, put message here');
    }
```

In your test you can now see the test what goes wrong (the message in assertTrue) and see, what test is failed (the name of the test).

Hope, this helps....

Comment: Thank you very much, assertTrue variables works for that purpose.